# How do I check if values in one DataFrame are also values of another DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning

I have two dataframes, both with columns FirstName and LastName. I want to see if anyone in df_mini is also in df_master. This is what I have so far:

```
for person in df_mini:
    if (df_mini.FirstName == df_master.FirstName) and (df_mini.LastName == df_master.LastName):
        df_mini['Is Duplicate?'].append('Yes')
    else:
        df_mini['Is Duplicate?'].append('No')
```

I'm getting an error that says "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects". There's probably something simple that I'm missing. I know there's an `isin` method, but I only see how I could use that if I were comparing one column.

Edit:

Just to give some more information--df_master has 60,000 values and df_mini has about 300. I need to check every value in df_mini against df_master.

df_mini columns:
stg_signup_id, cons_id, signup_form_name, create_dt, email, FirstName   LastName, phone, zip, source, subsource, Opt-In, isDuplicate

df_master columns: ID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Suffix, Home Phone, Address, City, State/Province, Zip/Postal, Zip4, CountryCode

Comment: Use `merge` and merge on first and last name. You can use outer with indicator to locate first and lastnames in both dataframes.  If you provide sample input, SO will show you how.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

**Solution**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

duplicate_indices = df_mini.merge(df_master, on=['FirstName', 'LastName'], how='inner').index
df_mini['isDuplicate'] = np.where(df_mini.index.isin(duplicate_indices), 'Yes', 'No')
```

**Output**

```
    FirstName   LastName    isDuplicate
0   bob         dylan       Yes
1   alan        partridge   No
2   steve       carell      No
```

**Example DataFrames**

```
df_mini = pd.DataFrame({
    'FirstName': ['bob', 'alan', 'steve'],
    'LastName': ['dylan', 'partridge', 'carell']
})

df_master = pd.DataFrame({
    'FirstName': ['jeff', 'boris', 'bob'],
    'LastName': ['bezos', 'johnson', 'dylan']
})
```

Comment: This runs, but I'm getting a lot of false positives. df_master (but not df_mini) has a MiddleName column--could that be throwing a wrench in things? df_master also has an Address field. If John Adams lives on Williams St, would it say that's a dupe for John Williams? Or is it only checking FirstName and LastName?